# PHP how to replace \\ with \ using preg_replace

Tags: php

i want to replace `\\` with `\` in PHP i tried this code but it doesn't work any idea ?

```
$var= preg_replace('/\\\\/', "\\", $var);
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [stripcslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) or [stripslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) instead. There is no good reason for regular expressions here and on the other hand they are more expensive than the built-in functions.

Comment: stripslashes() wouldn't necessarily work in his case (maybe his strings are messed up and he has \\ and \ at some places), but stripcslashes sound like a good idea.

Comment: Thats the reason I posted both ;) *str_replace()* is another solution. But regex are oversized when just replacing static strings with other static strings.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you want to use preg_replace ? You should be using str_replace :

```
php > echo str_replace("\\\\", "\\", "I\\\\'ve had");
I\'ve had
```

The problem is that with preg_replace, you have to escape the `\` for PHP's interpreter AND you have to escape `\` again for regexp's interpreter. So basically, you'd have to write this :

```
php > echo preg_replace("/\\\\\\\\/", "\\", "I\\\\'ve had");
I\'ve had
```

Because to write a `\` in a php string, you have to write `\\`, but you have to escape both for regexp's interpreter, and it becomes `\\\\`. That's a single `\`, so you have to repeat it twice.